# Why does tr fail with é?

Tags: bash

When I run `echo é | tr é e` i get `ee`, not the `e` I was expecting.

Here's the result of the command `locale` :

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Good question. It also happens with other accent letters, but not with other characters, like `^` or `$`.

Comment: Show the output of running the `locale` command.

Comment: @glennjackman: I have the same issue while all my `locale` entries are `"C.UTF-8"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like `tr` doesn't handle wide characters well.

```sh
$ echo 'é' | od -c
0000000   �   �  \n
0000003
$ echo 'é' | tr 'é' e | od -c
0000000   e   e  \n
0000003
```

Since the left-hand character set is 2 <strike>characters</strike> bytes long, `tr` repeats the last character of the right-hand set until it is the same length.

```sh
$ echo 123456789 | tr 2468 xy
1x3y5y7y9
```

You might prefer `sed` for handling non-ASCII characters.

```sh
$ echo 'é' | sed 's/é/e/g' | od -c
0000000   e  \n
0000002
$ echo 'é' | sed 'y/é/e/' | od -c
0000000   e  \n
0000002
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I think you are correct. As a practical matter `sed` will be a valid solution. To be clear, Are you saying the 'é' , aka '\130' is actually two characters wide? ( maybe 2 bytes wide?) And, as a result, `tr` successfully transliterates the two characters it received as input as requested. The only failure here is my understanding of the `tr` command or it's input. Right?

Comment: Yeah, my wording is probably insufficiently precise. It's probably a bytes versus characters problem: tr appears to be byte-oriented, sed is character-oriented.

Answer (score 1):

'é' is two characters wide and will produce 'ee' when using `tr`.

```
$ echo 'é' | tr 'é' 'e'
ee
```

Transliterate 'é' into two characters, a literal 'e' followed by '\b' a backspace to remove the second 'e'.

```
$ echo 'é' | od -c
0000000   �   �  \n
0000003

$ echo é | tr 'é' 'e\b' |od -c
0000000   e  \b  \n
0000003
```

EDIT: This approach is flawed. `$ echo é | tr 'é' 'e\b'` looks like it works but may produce odd results. While you see an 'e' on your terminal in actuality your terminal displays 'e\b'. That is an 'e' followed by a non-printing backspace character. Better off using `sed`.  `sed 'y|é|e|'`